# Javascript is using wrong textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate in Javascript. When I execute my calculation I can see that the script is using the textboxes multiple times.

**For example:**

The calculation for the first row is:

```
100 + 20 = 120
```

The calculation for the second row is:

```
100 + 0 = 100
```

The total should be **220**.

When I execute the code I get a total of **240**.

Does someone know why my script is not calculating properly?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjybzg3t/

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '[id^=neg_pos]', function selectQuantity(selectedValue) {
  let neg = 0
  let pos = 0

  $('[id^=neg_pos]').each(function(i, e) {
    var quantity = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (quantity === '0') {

    } else if (quantity === '1') {
      var num1 = Number(document.getElementsByName('price[]')[0].value);
      var num2 = Number(document.getElementsByName('tax[]')[0].value);

      var tv1 = num1 + num2;
      pos += tv1;

    } else {
      var num3 = Number(document.getElementsByName('price[]')[0].value);
      var num4 = Number(document.getElementsByName('tax[]')[0].value);

      var tv5 = num3 + num4;
      neg += tv5;
    }

    document.getElementById('positive').value = pos.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('negative').value = neg.toFixed(2);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="1">
<input type="text" name="tax[]" id="tax1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="1">
<select id="neg_pos1" name="neg_pos[]" data-srno="1" class="form-control">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price2" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="2">
<input type="text" name="tax[]" id="tax2" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="2">
<select id="neg_pos2" name="neg_pos[]" data-srno="2" class="form-control">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price3" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="3">
<input type="text" name="tax[]" id="tax3" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="3">
<select id="neg_pos3" name="neg_pos[]" data-srno="3" class="form-control">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br /><br /><br />

<input type="text" name="positive" id="positive" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)">
<input type="text" name="negative" id="negative" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your are using `document.getElementsByName('price[]')[0].value` to get the value of the input. But that code specifically selects the first `price[]` element, so you are always using the same value.

You need to replace `[0]` with `[i]` since `i` corresponds to the relevant `[id^=neg_pos]` item (*from `$('[id^=neg_pos]').each( function( i, e) {`*).

updated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/pjybzg3t/1/